# Windows 10 Hyper-v with LinuxMint 20

Tags: installation, linux-mint, hyper-v

I'm trying to install linuxmint as a VM with hyper-v.  When It gets to Installation type I have two options:

1. erase disk and install linux mint
2. something else

Not sure what to do at this point.  My windows machine is loaded on my c drive and I have the ISO and VM set up on my e drive

Comment: The "disk" in that context would be the virtual disk you made for the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two options always show up while booting of  a linux live cd, whether you are running it on virtual machine of from direct live cd.

A pro tip -
Just do some searches before posting

Something else - will let you manually partition drive, will allow you to create create different partitions for home, var, boot etc.

Erase and install linux mint - self-explanatory , will remove everything and install mint

Go with 'erase and install mint' option as you are running it on VM